# Convert an XML String to a JSON Object Object

Tags: java, xml, json, transformation

I'm trying to convert an XML string to a JSON object.  I used net.sf.json, but it strips away the root element.

```
XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
net.sf.json.JSON netsfJSON = xmlSerializer.read(xml);
```

I also tried org.json.XML

```
JSONObject jsonObject=XML.toJSONObject(xml);
```

but it doesn't differentiate the attributes from the elements.  Is there anything else I can use or are there some settings in the two libraries above?

Answer (score 1):

After createing the `XMLSerializer` object you need to set the **forceTopLevelObject** property to true due to the fact that the default setting is false.

```
XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();

xmlSerializer.setForceTopLevelObject(true);
```

Hope this helps.

Carol